# running a simple sh script with systemD

Tags: systemd, upstart

I have added a script file as

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! (ps aux | grep evercam_media/bin/evercam_media | grep -v grep > /dev/null); then
    /opt/evercam_media/bin/evercam_media start
fi
```

and its saved in `/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh` path..

I have created a very simple systemD unit file as

```
[Unit]
Description=Evercam

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I have enabled it as well. But when ever I start it, nothing is happening. I am just getting those erorrs on `systemctl status evercam.service`

```
● evercam.service - Evercam
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/evercam.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2017-07-18 14:10:08 CEST; 167ms ago
  Process: 7329 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7329 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Can you please point what is wrong here?

Comment: I do not see any errors here. `Process: 7329 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Comment: But its not running as well `Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: Is the bash script needed ? Do you have a process running (look at `ps aux`) after `systemctl start` ?

Comment: No process is not running. and I need to run through bash

Comment: even the stright `/opt/evercam_media/bin/evercam_media start` not working in the service.

Comment: Why do you need *bash*? Whats the result when you start  *evercam_media start* directly?

Comment: Bash is only checking if its already not runing or not. when When I start the service I get no reults. no ok no error